# startMonitoringForRegion: deprecated

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, deprecated

The header in CLLLocationManager has this line:

```
- (void)startMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region
             desiredAccuracy:(CLLocationAccuracy)accuracy __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(__MAC_NA, __MAC_NA,__IPHONE_4_0, __IPHONE_6_0);
```

and in fact an app of mine using that reports a warning when compiling and archiving. Notwithstanding the Apple documentation still includes it hinting to no obsolescence. Even a web search for the problem returns no hit. What is the matter? Do I risk to lose this functionality with some users?

Answer (score 2):

Apples [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringForRegion%3adesiredAccuracy%3a) say this is deprecated and you should use `startMonitoringForRegion:` instead

The risk is the same as any deprecated method, it will eventually be removed so its better to remove it from your code where you can (the new method only exists in iOS 6+ so you still need to use the old one in older version)

Comment: In fact it was the second parameter to be deleted. I did not notice it. Thanks indeed.